# how to clean up black paint that spilled on exterior bricks

Tags: paint, brick

My upstairs neighbor (well she said her cat did it) spilled black paint on her deck/patio last summer.  It dripped for 10 minutes down the side of my exterior wall of my unit (outside).  It's spilled all over the light fixture and on the bricks.  We've had power washers try and get it off, but they weren't able to clean it up.  What are my options for cleaning this up?  The condo association is responsible for the exterior of the building, but they are not too diligent about cleaning this up.  I'm more concerned about the bricks.  The glass/metal light fixture can be replaced.  What are my options for getting this cleaned up correctly?

Comment: Do you know what type of paint it is? Your options will be different if it's gloss or emulsion (for example).

Comment: I do not, but I will ask her.

Comment: Have you seen & read through these? http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/3706/3138 & http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/181/3138 & http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/3087/3138

Comment: it was latex paint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider soda blasting.  It's like sand blasting but uses industrial baking soda.  One of the suggested uses is for removing graffiti from brick.

Comment: corn products are good for this too

Comment: what do you mean by corn?  I'm a programmer, so I only know what corn bread is.  Haha.

Comment: Not sure how they cleaned it up, but if you need the same thing done, call them up: Nate Zellner or Nick Bellino @ DUCTZ/HOODZ of Greater Madison Area @ 608-849-5308 .. it was under $200 to clean up the brick wall.

Comment: it was latex paint btw..